# set the random seed in julia generator of random numbers

Tags: julia

I would like to do a couple of checkings using the random generator for normal distributed numbers in julia. So what I would like is to obtain the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers.

Actually, I do random matrices, so I would like that both of my programs generate:

```
A = randn(dim,dim)                                                                                                                                                                           
H = (A + A')/sqrt(2)
```

the same H-matrix

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Updated answer, for Julia 0.7 onwards.

```
import Random
Random.seed!(1234)
dim = 5
A = randn(dim,dim)
H = (A + A')/sqrt(2)
```

Previous answer, for Julia 0.6 and earlier.

You are looking for the [`srand` function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/numbers/#Base.Random.srand), e.g.

```
srand(1234)
dim = 5
A = randn(dim,dim)
H = (A + A')/sqrt(2)
```

Will always produce the same results.

Comment: which is the range of the argument of srand?

Comment: There actually multiple versions of `srand`, try `methods(srand)` and `?srand` for more info.

Comment: The `srand` documentation link is dead.

Comment: @becko not anymore! :)

Comment: srand does not exist in Julia 0.7/1.0

Comment: hasn't ``srand`` been deprecated in Julia >1? Would you update your answer? Thanks.

Comment: Updated for modern Julia.

Answer (score 11):

In Julia 0.7/1.0, you can use `Random.seed!(1234);` https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/index.html#Generators-(creation-and-seeding)-1

Comment: I think it is the only function you can use now.

Answer (score 1):

I think Random.seed!(int) applies only on the next random for some reason. you need to reuse it every time you call. You can set the random seed as a function though like

```
function rr()
    rng = MersenneTwister(22);
    return rng
end
```

and then call in inside the rand() function like

```
rand(rr(), 1)
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAO99.png)