# ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (GF{7,Int64}) used in boolean context

Tags: types, julia

Surfing on the web I looked the way to solve linear systems equations over a finite field or [Galois field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field)

> - [1-whyjulia.ipynb](https://github.com/johnfgibson/whyjulia/blob/master/1-whyjulia.ipynb)
> - [Fast and Flexible Linear Algebra in Julia – CME 510](https://youtu.be/VS0fnUOAKpI?t=2362)

But the code is using a Julia version 0.4 or 0.5 or 0.6 because I want to check by hand the results.

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia

struct GF{p,T} <: Number where {p,T<:Integer}
    rep::T  # representative integer which holds the value of a GF(p) variable
    function GF{p,T}(x::Integer) where {p,T<:Integer}
        return new(mod(x, p))
    end
end

GF{p}(x::T) where {p,T<:Integer} = GF{p,T}(x)


import Base: convert, inv, one, promote_rule, show, zero, abs, conj, isless
#https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/issues/1139#issue-198117727
import Primes: isprime

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/58253283/9302545
function call(::Type{GF{p}}, x::Integer) where {p}
    if !isprime(p)
        throw(ArgumentError("p must be prime"))
    end
    return GF{p,typeof(x)}(mod(x, p))
end

convert(::Type{GF{p,T}}, x::Integer) where {p,T} = GF{p}(x)
convert(::Type{GF{p}}, x::Integer) where {p} = GF{p}(x)
convert(::Type{GF{p,T}}, x::GF{p}) where {p,T} = GF{p,T}(x.rep)
promote_rule(::Type{GF{p,T1}}, ::Type{T2}) where {p,T1,T2<:Integer} = GF{p,promote_type(T1, T2)}
show(io::IO, x::GF) = show(io, x.rep);
```

```
julia> subtypes(Number)
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 Complex
 GF
 Real

julia> GF{2}(11)
1

julia> x = GF{7}(9)   # x =  9 mod 7 = 2
2

julia> y = GF{7}(12)  # y = 12 mod 7 = 5
5
```

```
# Define arithmetic operations on GF(p)
import Base: +, -, *, /

for op in (:+, :-, :*)   # loop over ops, defining each in terms of integer ops mod p
    @eval begin
        ($op)(x::GF{p,T}, y::GF{p,T}) where {p,T} = GF{p,T}($(op)(x.rep, y.rep))
    end
end
```

```
julia> x, y = GF{5}(4), GF{5}(3)
(4, 3)

julia> @show x + y
x + y = 2
@show x - y
2

julia> @show x - y
x - y = 1
1

julia> @show x * y
x * y = 2
2
```

```
# Define inverse and ÷. Requires more care than +, -, * because dividing by zero throws error
function inv(x::GF{p,T}) where {p,T}
    if x == zero(x)
        throw(DivideError())
    end
    r, u, v = gcdx(x.rep, p)
    GF{p,T}(u)
end
(/)(x::GF{p,T}, y::GF{p,T}) where {p,T} = x * inv(y);

abs(x::GF{p,T}) where {p,T} = GF{p,T}(abs(x.rep))
conj(x::GF{p,T}) where {p,T} = GF{p,T}(conj(x.rep))
```

```
julia> @show x / y
x / y = 3
3

julia> @show x \ y # we get this by inheritance from number;
x \ y = 2
```

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/25006629/9302545
import Random
Random.seed!(1234); #srand(1234)
A = [GF{7}(rand(0:6)) for i = 1:4, j = 1:4]; # matrix of random GF(7) elems
A[1, 1] = 3;
A[1, 2] = 5;
A[1, 3] = 3;
A[1, 4] = 3;
A[2, 1] = 6;
A[2, 2] = 6;
A[2, 3] = 2;
A[2, 4] = 0;
A[3, 1] = 2;
A[3, 2] = 2;
A[3, 3] = 6;
A[3, 4] = 4;
A[4, 1] = 2;
A[4, 2] = 6;
A[4, 3] = 1;
A[4, 4] = 2;
```

```
julia> A#[3 5 3 3; 6 6 2 0; 2 2 6 4; 2 6 1 2]]
4×4 Array{GF{7,Int64},2}:
 3  5  3  3
 6  6  2  0
 2  2  6  4
 2  6  1  2
```

```
b = [GF{7}(rand(0:6)) for i = 1:4];# random vector b for Ax=b problem
b[1] = 1;
b[2] = 4;
b[3] = 3;
b[4] = 0;
```

```
julia> b
4-element Array{GF{7,Int64},1}:
 1
 4
 3
 0
```

```
x = A \ b   # solve Ax=b over GF(p)!
```

Then, later of done partial solutions (lines with comments of stackoverflow), I have the last error on the last line of the above chunk.

I would like if someone can help me with this last step.

```
julia> x = A \ b   # solve Ax=b over GF(p)!
ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (GF{7,Int64}) used in boolean context
Stacktrace:
 [1] generic_lufact!(::Array{GF{7,Int64},2}, ::Val{true}; check::Bool) at /build/julia/src/julia-1.5.3/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/LinearAlgebra/src/lu.jl:146
 [2] #lu!#134 at /build/julia/src/julia-1.5.3/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/LinearAlgebra/src/lu.jl:130 [inlined]
 [3] #lu#136 at /build/julia/src/julia-1.5.3/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/LinearAlgebra/src/lu.jl:273 [inlined]
 [4] lu at /build/julia/src/julia-1.5.3/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/LinearAlgebra/src/lu.jl:272 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [5] \(::Array{GF{7,Int64},2}, ::Array{GF{7,Int64},1}) at /build/julia/src/julia-1.5.3/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/LinearAlgebra/src/generic.jl:1116
```

I am starting with Julia v.1.5.3 and [Primes.jl](https://juliamath.github.io/Primes.jl/stable) v.0.5.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Przemyslaw wrote you are still missing some other functions. I could run your code as it is now just by adding the function `isless`.
I.e.

```
(isless)(x::GF{p,T}, y::GF{p,T}) where {p,T} = isless(x.rep, y.rep)
```

Of course, if you're still getting more of these undefined errors you should add also the new functions.

By the way, the isless function you wrote in the comments is wrong. `isless` returns either `true` or `false` (it is either less or it is not), you're trying to return it a `GF{p,T}(::Bool)`, which as the error points out doesn't exist, since the value of rep can only be an Integer, not a Bool.

The result then should be

```
julia> x = A \ b
4-element Array{GF{7,Int64},1}:
 5
 5
 0
 1
```

Comment: Thank so much both Oskar and @przemyslaw-szufel, I learned a lot with this details (I was lost). It works and now I will check other linear systems from exercise sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is defining a custom numeric type so you need to provide missing numeric function from `Base`. Here `abs` is missing and hence you could do:

```
import Base.abs
abs(x::GF{p,T}) where {p,T} = GF{abs(p),T}(abs(x.rep))
```

Once you do it, perhaps you are going to discover that some other functions are missing and you can add them in a similar way.

Comment: Thank you so much, what is the difference between `abs(x::GF{p,T}) where {p,T} = GF{p,T}(abs(x.rep))` and the above.

Since that `abs` is an unary operation works, but if I try to defined `isless(x::GF{p,T}, y::GF{p,T}) where {p,T} = GF{p,T}(isless(x.rep, y.rep))` it will be wrong? I have other error `ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (GF{7,Int64}) used in boolean context`.

Comment: The difference depends on how you define `abs` for your numbers (it is your decision, not mine). Your `isless` looks fine to me. Just remember to import it before defining. The last error is self-explanatory - you need to look at the source code.